# Storing hyperlink for Excel using Python3/SQLite3

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, syntax, sqlite

I have a python function that generates the following text:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://v1.test.com/VersionOne/assetdetail.v1?Number=S-13688", "S-13688")
```

This text is perfectly formatted to show up as a hyperlink in a spreadsheet/CSV file if I can get it inserted into a cell in Excel, but sqlite3 is throwing an error that I cannot get past.

*note - the url is the "text" shown above and gets inserted into the second set of brackets below:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../modules/report_tickets_open.py", line 158, in <module>
    cur.execute( ''' UPDATE rpt_tickets_open SET "V1 URL #{}" = {} WHERE "Incident ID" = "{}" '''.format(str(y+1), settings.newURL, id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "https": syntax error
```

Is there any way for me to ignore the syntax error that sqlite3 is throwing so that python will go ahead and insert the text as it is currently formatted?

Comment: I can pass strings with the text/hyperlink in it all day long using Python. It only seems to fall apart and generate errors when I try to store the text/hyperlink in a sqlite table.

Comment: I have tried just about every permutation of the text/hyperlink that I can come up with, but if the string begins with `=HYPERLINK(...` I continue to get the sqlite3.OperationalError. Interestingly enough, if I only pass the actual hyperlink (e.g., `https://v1.test.com/VersionOne/assetdetail.v1?Number=S-13688`), I don’t get the OperationalError from SQLite.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out why the text/hyperlink won’t store in SQLite. I created a workaround where I store the true hyperlink (i.e., `"https://v1.test.com/VersionOne/assetdetail.v1?Number=S-13688"`) in SQLite, and then tack on all of the other pieces to cobble together the Excel formula so that it will show up in my spreadsheet as an appropriately configured hyperlink (i.e., so that the end result in my spreadsheet looks like `=HYPERLINK("https://v1.test.com/VersionOne/assetdetail.v1?Number=S-13688", "S-13688”`).

Answer (score 0):

Answering in case anybody else runs into this in the future:

Unable to figure out why I couldn’t store Excel-formatted hyperlinks in SQLite. SQLite doesn’t like them, but there doesn’t seem to be a rule or reason for the error that it throws when you try to use them.

Bottom line is - don’t try to store the Excel-formatted hyperlinks in SQLite; figure out a different way to get it done.